# Change line feed of csv file to the same one

Tags: php, csv, linefeed

I need to work with csv files. I want to write an web app which is working with csv files and is written in php.
Problem is all the csv files have diffrent line feeds /r, /n,/r/n/.
I need to have the same in all of them.
Till now i do it like this:

```
exec("sed -i 's/\r$//' files/uploads/$fileName"); // DOS to Unix
exec("sed -i 's/$/\r/' files/uploads/$fileName"); // Unix to DOS
```

And in the end all of them have /r/n.
But what if i get a csv file with /r as line feed, how to deal with that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options right in php. For example:

```
$f=file_get_contents("files/uploads/$fileName");
$f=str_replace("\r","",$f);
file_put_contents("files/uploads/$filename",$f);
```

This will strip all RETURN characters ("\r") from the input and write the file back with just linefeeds ("\n").

I have yet to see a CSV/Spreadsheet file with just "\r" characters, but supposing that is the case you could also do: str_replace("\r","\n") and then reduce "\n\n" to a single "\n" (again using str_replace).

There is also a REGEX-based solution, but the regex-part of my brain is a little fried this morning.

Comment: Problem here is, this will remove the /r, but afterwards the whole content will be seen as one line instead of an csv file with multiple lines

Comment: Not really, the \n (or linefeed) will still be there. That's what will separate the lines.